# SyntaxError when installing modules

Tags: python

When I try to install packages, e.g. pypdf2, I get a syntax error: [image]

I tried to change the environment variables like is done in other questions on this topic but I do not succeed in solving this problem. Can someone provide a step-by-step walkthrough in solving this problem for a Python beginner?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute `pip install` as if it is a python command: but it isn't.

You need to execute all pip commands from the normal O/S command line - since you are in Pycharm you can simply type those pip commands from the Terminal window (the one you used to try to run the script).

Comment: No need to re-answer a repeated duplicate. There are many well-explained answers there already

Comment: It wasn't marked as a duplicate when i answered.